# Javascript Web Push: where can I get "auth" key?

Tags: javascript, web-push, web-notifications

I'm starting to use Web Push Notification; I don't know where I can find the `auth` key:

```
var pushSubscription = {
  endpoint: '< Push Subscription URL >',
  keys: {
    p256dh: '< User Public Encryption Key >',
    auth: '< ???? User Auth Secret ???? >'
  }
};
```

I can get `endpoint` and `p256dh` from `ServiceWorker>registeration.pushManager.getSubscription()` but not the `auth` key.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `getKey` method to get both `p256dh` and `auth` (see [the specs](https://w3c.github.io/push-api/#widl-PushSubscription-getKey-ArrayBuffer-PushEncryptionKeyName-name) or [the example from the specs](https://w3c.github.io/push-api/#example)).

It's even simpler to just call `JSON.stringify` on the `PushSubscription` object returned by the `getSubscription` promise.

Comment: if you want to use the object (get the keys) in JS, do not fiddle around with ab2string convertions or pushSubscription.keyKeys()... (Spoiler: won't work.) Just do this: 
`var subJSObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(pushSubscription)); 
var endpoint = subJSObject.endpoint; 
var auth = subJSObject.keys.auth; var p256dh = subJSObject.keys.p256dh;`

Comment: @mondjunge You are absolutely right. I chose the hard way and the maximum I could get from all these methods were gibberish. Next time I will look over the specific issue at hand instead try the general solutions like try finding convertion methods.

Answer (score 9):

Using Typescript, the `PushSubscription` object should have a method on it called `toJSON`.  Just use that.

```
const sub: PushSubscription = YOUR_RAW_PUSH_SUBSCRIPTION;
const pushSubscription = {
  endpoint: sub.endpoint,
  expirationTime: sub.expirationTime,
  keys: {
    p256dh: sub.toJSON().keys.p256dh,
    auth: sub.toJSON().keys.auth
  }
};
```

Comment: It'd be slightly more efficient to only call `sub.toJSON()` once and store it in a constant.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.swPush.requestSubscription({serverPublicKey: 'BPffxa1Lf3WJuqc-OLSRCYdYteLAzXHZhAxHUXcEgiBUpHzeJUBq9M6k44f8YeSs4ckVLWCYyvbviLBnknXnTKU'})
  .then(subscription => {        
    this.p256dhKey = this.getBase64Url(subscription.getKey('p256dh')!);
    this.authKey = this.getBase64Url(subscription.getKey('auth')!);
    this.endpoint = subscription.endpoint;
  })
  .catch(error => console.error('Error requesting subscription:', error));
```